Can the properties of the Snap event tell why sanp event lister call back does get executed despite snapping occures to edges and vertices
I register for Draw, Modify and Snap interactions as shown below in the code. The interactions added to the map are working except the Snap.
to debug this issue, i printed the contents of this.#snapEvt and it is as displayed in the screen-shot attached below.
Does the contents of this.#snapEvt displayed in the screen shot can reveal in any way why the snapping evetn does get fired? in other words, why despite the mouse snaps to the edges and vertices of a feature, neither the.#evtListenerOnSnap nor the log statement snapped get executed or displayed? Unlinke the other interactions added to the map Draw and Modify
code:
// for debugging purposes, the following code was added in the event listener callback of 'addfeature' to ensure that the `vectorSource` used to instantiate the below mentioned object is updated.

this.#snapEvt = this.#mapBuilderInstance.getSnapGeomForSource(this.#vectorSource);
this.#mapInstance = this.#mapBuilderInstance.addInteractionEvtToMap(this.#mapInstance, this.#drawEvt);
this.#mapInstance = this.#mapBuilderInstance.addInteractionEvtToMap(this.#mapInstance, this.#modifyEvt);
this.#mapInstance = this.#mapBuilderInstance.addInteractionEvtToMap(this.#mapInstance, this.#snapEvt);
this.#snapEvt.setActive(true)
this.#keyOnEvtSnap = this.#snapEvt.on('snap', evt =>  {
        console.log('snapped')
        this.#evtListenerOnSnap(evt)
    });

getSnapGeomForSource(src) {
    return new Snap({ 
        source: src,
        pixelTolerance: 30,
     });
}

addInteractionEvtToMap(map, evt) {
    if (map) {
        if (evt) {
            map.addInteraction(evt);
            return map;
        }
    }
}

contents of this.#snapEvt


So snap event does not get fired at all? No matter is you do draw or modify?

@TomazicM yes exactly. I can draw a feature and modify it and mouse cursor snaps to the vertices and edges and the event listeners callback of ‘modify’ and ‘draw’ get executed, but for the ‘snap’ event, it’s callback listener never gets executed as mentioned in my question.

For me it works without problems in plain JS, see JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/6k937ecq/
